# How can I find all subforms of main TForm Application object?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am working on an application for Windows and OSX and I'd like to find all the subforms of the main TForm object in the Application.

Is there a way to do this in Delphi XE5? Simply, I'd like to iterate all components of the application.

Moved to the question from the comments:

> I'm looking to find every `TForm` descendant in `Application`.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "subform of main TForm object in Application".

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want sub forms of the main form of the application you are in? Or an external application?

Comment: Yes, sub forms of the main form of the application

Comment: What do you consider to be a "sub form" exactly? A TForm that has the MainForm set as its `Owner` and/or `Parent`?  Please be more specific.

Comment: @Xsawery we don't know what sub form means. You must define your terms, unless you use standard terminology.

Comment: I think every component created in application have parent... and I'm looking for the way to use it, and find every TForm descendant in Application.

Comment: -1 because you were pretty unclear about what you are actually asking and refused to clarify your question when asked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean any form created via the application's main form in a manner like this?

```
procedure TMyMainForm.CreateSubForm;
begin
   TMySubForm.Create(Self);
end;
```

Try this

```
procedure FindMainFormSubForms(list : TList<TForm>);
var
    i : integer;
    mainForm : TForm;
begin
    mainForm := Application.MainForm;
    for i := 0 to mainForm.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
        if mainForm.Components[i] is TForm then
            list.Add(TForm(mainForm.Components[i]));
    end;
end;
```

Comment: A similar approach can be used if the `MainForm` is the `Parent` of the sub TForm objects, by iterating the `Controls[]` list instead of the `Components[]` list.

Comment: And what about forms that are created in run-time... and assigned to the global variable in project main Unit.pas file? Are they also on Components[] list?

Comment: What if the form is created without an owner? I do that habitually.

Comment: If it hasn't got the main form as either its owner or parent I'm not sure you could call it a "sub-form" of the main form. At that point you'd have to maintain your own list on the main form, in which case you'd already have a reference to them and there's no question to answer. My answer does state it's assumptions up front and it's pretty poorly worded question

Comment: @JTolley From the comments to the question: "find every TForm descendant in Application"

Comment: That's a valid response but my answer was before that comment and I haven't edited it to reflect the clarification. That may mean my answer is not the one that should be accepted. I'm entirely fine with that.

Comment: It's cool. The question was very vague. And still is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 3):

In FMX you use the [`TScreen.Forms[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TScreen.Forms) property to enumerate all form objects in the application:

```
for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
  DoSomethingWith(Screen.Forms[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

All forms of the total application reside in [`Screen.CustomForms`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/CustomForms_(Delphi)). You could iterate over them using [`Screen.CustomFormCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.CustomFormCount).

### Filter options:

- If you only want forms that are owned by the main form, check for `Screen.CustomForms[I].Owner = Application.MainForm;`
- If you only want forms that are parented by the main form, check for `Screen.CustomForms[I].Parent = Application.MainForm;`

### MDI:

If your main form is an MDI Form, and you would like to know all its MDI child forms, then all child forms reside in [`(Application.)MainForm.MDIChildren`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/MDIChildren_(Delphi)), which you could iterate over by using [`(Application.)MainForm.MDIChildCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.MDIChildCount).